# Android multi flavor library module used into application module

Tags: android, gradle, module, static-libraries, android-productflavors

I'm trying to setup an project which relies on a library module which uses ".so" files.

Until now I have:

## library module

- .so files into jniLibs: armeabi, armeabi-v7a and x86.
- this is the Android.mk file used for configuration:

```
# Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)

LOCAL_MODULE := my-module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/my-lib.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

- this is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call

    // By default set the publish flavor to
    defaultPublishConfig "X86Debug"
    publishNonDefault true

    productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilter("armeabi")
            }
        }
        arm7 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter("x86")
            }
        }
        // This is the fat apk which includes all the ABIs
        fat
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
}
```

## application module

- this is the build.gradle:

```
...

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...

android {
    
    ...

    // In case more than one filter should be applied for the flavors, the order is important
    flavorDimensions "api", "abi"

    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            dimension "api"
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }

        prod {
            dimension "api"
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt((String) project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        }

        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        arm {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter("armeabi")
            }
        }
        arm7 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }
        x86 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter("x86")
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Disable all components for debug
            debuggable false
            // Use the updated proguard rules
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Obfuscate, clean and optimize project code
            minifyEnabled true
            // Enable zip align for optimizations
            zipAlignEnabled true

            //Only use the release key on a release buildType
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true

            minifyEnabled false

            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
    }

    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

configurations {
    // x86 versions
    devX86DebugCompile
    prodX86DebugCompile
    devX86ReleaseCompile
    prodX86ReleaseCompile

    // arm versions
    devArmDebugCompile
    prodArmDebugCompile
    devArmReleaseCompile
    prodArmReleaseCompile

    // arm7 versions
    devArm7DebugCompile
    prodArm7DebugCompile
    devArm7ReleaseCompile
    prodArm7ReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    devX86DebugCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'x86Debug')
    prodX86DebugCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'x86Debug')
    devX86ReleaseCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'x86Release')
    prodX86ReleaseCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'x86Release')
    devArmDebugCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'armDebug')
    prodArmDebugCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'armDebug')
    devArmReleaseCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'armRelease')
    prodArmReleaseCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'armRelease')
    devArm7DebugCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'arm7Debug')
    prodArm7DebugCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'arm7Debug')
    devArm7ReleaseCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'arm7Release')
    prodArm7ReleaseCompile project(path: ':my-module-lib', configuration: 'arm7Release')

    ...
}
```

This seems to currently work(at least when compiling), but I feel it is hard to maintain it like this, and I'll have to add a lot of dependencies and configurations (in the end I want to support all ABIs, to make an apk for each one).

Is there an easier and cleaner way to do something like this?

<s>Also, in the generated APKs all ABIs are included. I'm doing something wrong for this?</s>

## LE

I've fixed the issue with all the ABIs being included into the APKs. I just needed to use the abiFilter in the productFlavors of the application module.
I've updated my code to reflect this.
Only a small issue for this I noticed: The resulting aar of the library module still includes all ABIs, even though it has the abiFilter set correctly for each flavor.